# docker-compose network error cant connect to other host

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and I'm having issues with connecting to my managed database cluster on the cloud services which was separated from the docker machine and network.

So recently I attempted to use docker-compose because manually writing docker run command every update is a hassle so I configure the yml file.

Whenever I use docker compose, I'm having issues connecting to the database with this error

```
Unhandled error event: Error: connect ENOENT %22rediss://default:password@test.ondigitalocean.com:25061%22
```

But if I run it on the actual docker run command with the ENV in dockerfile, then everything will work fine.

```
docker run -d -p 4000:4000 --restart always test
```

But I don't want to expose all the confidential data to the code repository with all the details on the dockerfile.

Here is my dockerfile and docker-compose

dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.3.0
WORKDIR /kpb
COPY package.json /kpb
RUN npm install
COPY . /kpb
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    app:
        container_name: kibblepaw-graphql
        restart: always
        build: .
        ports: 
            - '4000:4000'
        environment: 
            - PRODUCTION="${PRODUCTION}"
            - DB_SSL="${DB_SSL}"
            - DB_CERT="${DB_CERT}"
            - DB_URL="${DB_URL}"
            - REDIS_URL="${REDIS_URL}"
            - SESSION_KEY="${SESSION_KEY}"
            - AWS_BUCKET_REGION="${AWS_BUCKET_REGION}"
            - AWS_BUCKET="${AWS_BUCKET}"
            - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
            - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the `"` for the values of your environment variables in your docker-compose.

This should work:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    app:
        container_name: kibblepaw-graphql
        restart: always
        build: .
        ports: 
            - '4000:4000'
        environment: 
            - PRODUCTION=${PRODUCTION}
            - DB_SSL=${DB_SSL}
            - DB_CERT=${DB_CERT}
            - DB_URL=${DB_URL}
            - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}
            - SESSION_KEY=${SESSION_KEY}
            - AWS_BUCKET_REGION=${AWS_BUCKET_REGION}
            - AWS_BUCKET=${AWS_BUCKET}
            - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
            - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I understood the error now. That's why I see %22.